# jQuery rotating an image in two directions after a certain time

Tags: jquery, html

I'm currently trying to expand my jQuery knowledge by trying to re-create cool demos of projects I come across online. The one I'm working on now is the spinning eyeball on http://www.beautyoftheweb.com/#/private, but I'm having trouble finding a way to make my images rotate in two directions.

I'm using a set of layered images like they do on that website, and I've gotten a nice smooth rotation in two different directions for the individual images. My current code looks like this:

```
var angle = 0,
    angle2 = 0,
    angle3 = 0,
    angle4 = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
      angle += 0.5;
     $("#3").rotate(angle);
},30);
setInterval(function(){
      angle2 -= 0.025;
     $("#2").rotate(angle2);
},10);
setInterval(function(){
      angle3 += 0.25;
     $("#5").rotate(angle3);
},10);
setInterval(function(){
      angle4 -= 0.025;
     $("#4").rotate(angle4);
},10);
```

I'm using jQueryRotate as well with this, and everything works great as it is. Is there some way to implement a feature that will allow this to run for X amount of seconds, after which I can call another rotation, so it would go in two directions? Something like:

```
angle +=0.25;
    run for 3-4 seconds
angle -=0.25;
    run for 1 second
angle +=0.25; 
    run for 2 seconds
angle +=0.125;
    run for 1 second
```

Comment: "ie9 - leaps and bounds ahead?!!", is this a spoof site?

Comment: Although pasting your javascript here for us to look at is helpful, this sort of problem would benefit from an example JSFiddle.

Comment: You could maybe save the return value of your setIntervals and create setTimeouts that then call clearInterval and set up new intervals

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle of some of my code - http://jsfiddle.net/VUvgE/. I'm also not really sure how to do that MrOBrian, do you have any examples of how that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature that you're looking for sounds like the setTimeout() method in javascript.

Here is a good resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

What you can do is use setInterval() to run a function that calls setTimeout() functions on the indvidual angles. This will make it loop over a certain interval, like your original sample. Just set your first rotation for a certain length, and then chain the other animations accordingly.

A code example would be like: http://jsfiddle.net/avCx5/6/

**UPDATE** I removed the old code, as there was an error. In most browsers, using a function parameter in setTimeout will cause it to execute immediately. In the above example, the first animation runs for 3 seconds, then the second animation runs for 3 seconds, then they are both stopped. (I unstacked the images for clarity).

Here is a crude example that will run indefinitely: http://jsfiddle.net/avCx5/7/

In order to properly answer, here is the code:

HTML

```
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/w7dQh.png" class="overlay" id="1" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/isx4q.png" class="overlay" id="2" />​
```

jQuery

```
   var angle = 0,
       angle2 = 0,
       angle3 = 0;

   var angle1rotation;
   var angle2rotation;

   function rotation1() {
      angle1rotation = setInterval(function() {
        angle3 += 0.25;
        $("#1").rotate(angle3);
      }, 10);

   }

 function rotation2() {
      angle2rotation = setInterval(function() {
         angle2 -= 0.5;
         $("#2").rotate(angle2);
      }, 10);
  }

  function animation_sequence() {
     rotation1();
     window.setTimeout(function(){
       clearInterval(angle1rotation);
       rotation2();
     }, 3000);
     window.setTimeout(function(){
       clearInterval(angle2rotation);        
     }, 6000);   
   }

   var main_loop = setInterval(function(){
      animation_sequence();
   }, 8000);


   animation_sequence();
```

Comment: This is useful, but I can't figure out how to implement it properly - when I run this code as is, it just basically spins my images to infinity. I was trying to add a delay with something like this http://jsfiddle.net/avCx5/ , but I was unable to get it to work. Is there a way to stop a function at X seconds? I feel that something like that might work too.

Comment: The clearInterval call should effectively stop the rotation function. By calling that in a set interval, its essentially like running the animation until it is cleared. I would start with 1 animation at a time, and then build up from there. The code I provided was just a quick skeleton, so I'm not super surprised it didn't work.

Comment: Steps to get a working solution from this would be to focus on single animations, get all of the animations you want working right on their own. Then I would try turning 1 on and off using setInterval(). Once you have a good handle on this, move to two, and eventually you'll have your results.

Comment: The JSFiddle in your answer looks like it's exactly what I want - I think I'll be able to deconstruct this and make it work for what I need. Thank you!